# Redux-Toolkit createAsyncThunk request to firestore returns undefined

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am learning react and have started on a personal project using redux, redux-toolkit and firestore to store data. I have a problem with fetching and storing data that I cannot solve. Its entirely possible that I'm using a wrong approach to the problem or I've forced myself to a dead-end from a technical perspective (I am a noob after all), so any suggestions are welcome. On to the matter at hand.

Everything I have made so far works, in the sense that firestore receives the request and stores data as requested, however the code is not technically correct as you will see in the snippets bellow. I've been using **createAsyncThunk** from redux toolkit to handle requests and it seems to be working, but something seems a bit off in the code. If I use setDoc(), for example, to update a field in firestore, the return value is `undefined` (i.e. `Promise<void>`), as per the documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.md#updatedoc and I'm not sure how to handle it. Bellow I have shared the snippets required for making an update on the users document.

**Initialize Firebase and define an update function (FIREBASE__CONFIG omitted):**

```
const app = initializeApp(FIREBASE_CONFIG);
const dbFB = getFirestore(app);

export const updateFB = async (url, id, values) => {
    const docRef = doc(dbFB, url, id);
    const docResponse = await updateDoc(docRef, values);
    
    return docResponse;
};
```

**Define user slice (omitting configureStore here for brevity):**

```
const initialState = {
    isLoggedIn: false,
    userDetails: null,
};

const userSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'user',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        ...
    },
    extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(userUpdate.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      state.userDetails = { ...state.userDetails, ...action.payload };
    });
    }
});
```

**Define userUpdate action (the requestError dispatch is an update for another slice):**

```
export const userUpdate = createAsyncThunk(
    'user/userUpdate',
    async ({ userId, values }, { dispatch }) => {
        try {
            const usersRes = await updateFB('/users', userId, values);      
            return usersRes;
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
            dispatch(httpActions.requestError({ errorMessage: err.message || 'Something went wrong!'}));
        }
    }
);
```

**Calling the update request on submit (using FormIK):**

```
<Formik
    ...
    onSubmit={async (values, { setSubmitting }) => {
        dispatch(userUpdate({userId: userDetails.userId, values})).then(() => {
            setSubmitting(false);
            history.push(MY_PROFILE.path);
        });
    }}
>
    {({ isSubmitting }) => (
        <Form>
            <div className='form-field'>
            ...
            </div>
        </Form>
    )}
</Formik>
```

As you can see, I would like to continue execution of some other commands after the request has resolved on form submission. However, the return value of this request is `undefined` and it feels off to use `.then()` on it, even though it works.
Perhaps I've gone completely off the beaten path?
Help is appreciated, thank you :)

Comment: You're using v9 but you're pointing out a documentation of v8. Have you also looked at the official docs of [v9](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.documentreference)?

Comment: @MarcAnthonyB thank you for the correction, however the v8 and v9 are very similar and the same applies to both. I have corrected my original post though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned, the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.md#updatedoc) stated that it will return `Promise<void>`. The reason behind: This is just a simple document **write operation** sent off to the server. If it did return the document data in the call, not only you'll need to **wait for the data to be sent back**, and you'll also be **billed for a document read** and bandwidth that is never needed.

If you need the updated data, you'll need to use `getDoc()` in a separate call. If you update multiple documents, you may need multiple `getDoc()` calls too. e.g:

```
export const updateFB = async (url, id, values) => {
    const docRef = doc(dbFB, url, id);
    const docResponse = await updateDoc(docRef, values);

    // Returns updated document.
    const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);
    console.log(docSnap.data());

    return docSnap.data();
};
```

Comment: In that case, do you think its correct to use an async function when submitting the form like so:


`onSubmit={async (values, { setSubmitting }) => {
        dispatch(userUpdate({userId: userDetails.userId, values})).then(() => {
            setSubmitting(false);
            history.push(MY_PROFILE.path);
        });
    }}`

p.s. sorry I don't know how to format code in comments

Comment: Async functions always return an implicit `Promise` and therefore, your form is still submitted. I would just suggest resolving your function everytime its called. To resolve it you can call the function and then return true or false.